# Where to Download .PAK Files for Dune Legacy

Tags: linux, dune-2, dune-legacy

I just installed *Dune Legacy* on Ubuntu and got a message saying that I need to download and properly save several .PAK files from the original *Dune II* game. I have never owned *Dune II*, so I do not already have the files. I googled some, as well as searched this stack exchange, and could not find any information regarding where to download these files. Where can they be found? I am looking for a free download.